# Flicker drawer in app when I try to get user name from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flicker

I am building my first Flutter app with custom drawer. It should display "Welcome" + name_of_user in the header of the drawer. But when I try to retrieve user data from firebase it shows me [red screen with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVt4M.png) for 1 second and then it behaves like [normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCRey.png). How can I fix that red screen?

```
FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
  String _uname;
  FirebaseAuth _auth;
  DocumentReference ref;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    _getCurrentUser();

  }
  _getCurrentUser () async {
    mCurrentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    DocumentSnapshot item = await Firestore.instance.collection("users").document(mCurrentUser.uid).get(); //If //I delete this line everything works fine but I don't have user name.
    _uname = item['fname'];
    setState(() {
    });
  }
```

Then I display name like this

```
 child: Text("Welcome " + _uname,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
        ]));
```

Console log

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/EGL_emulation(22382): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd7f1a7e0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xd7f0f900)
D/eglCodecCommon(22382): setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
W/DynamiteModule(22382): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Unsupported class loader
I/DynamiteModule(22382): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.flags:3 and remote module com.google.android.gms.flags:3
I/DynamiteModule(22382): Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.flags
I/DynamiteModule(22382): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(22382): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/ApplicationLoaders(22382): Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.jar
D/ApplicationLoaders(22382): Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.jar
D/ApplicationLoaders(22382): Returning zygote-cached class loader: /system/framework/android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.jar
I/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(22382): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@a5e5857
I/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 16121(979KB) AllocSpace objects, 13(376KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 1791KB/3583KB, paused 22.289ms total 224.233ms
I/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader;->pathList:Ldalvik/system/DexPathList; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->systemNativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryPathElements:[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->makePathElements(Ljava/util/List;)[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$NativeLibraryElement; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
V/NativeCrypto(22382): Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 284 native methods...
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(22382): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/ProviderInstaller(22382): Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->arrayBaseOffset(Ljava/lang/Class;)I (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->copyMemory(JJJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->objectFieldOffset(Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getByte(J)B (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getByte(Ljava/lang/Object;J)B (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putByte(JB)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putByte(Ljava/lang/Object;JB)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (greylist, JNI, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Lsun/security/x509/AlgorithmId;->get(Ljava/lang/String;)Lsun/security/x509/AlgorithmId; (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Lsun/security/x509/AlgorithmId;->getName()Ljava/lang/String; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
W/com.dsc.viu_ap(22382): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(22382): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@a5e5857
D/FirebaseAuth(22382): Notifying id token listeners about user ( UhkwQ6lvz3ZwYoBdLH6zod0Li353 ).
W/Firestore(22382): (19.0.0) [FirestoreCallCredentials]: Failed to get token: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: getToken aborted due to token change.
I/flutter (22382): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (22382): The following ArgumentError was thrown building AppDrawer(dirty, state: AppDrawerState#ebffb):
I/flutter (22382): Invalid argument(s)
I/flutter (22382): 
I/flutter (22382): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (22382): #0      _StringBase.+ (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:260:57)
I/flutter (22382): #1      AppDrawerState._createHeader (package:viu_app/widget/drawer.dart:110:38)
I/flutter (22382): #2      AppDrawerState.build (package:viu_app/widget/drawer.dart:41:11)
I/flutter (22382): #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4012:27)
I/flutter (22382): #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:15)
I/flutter (22382): #5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
I/flutter (22382): #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
I/flutter (22382): #8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
I/flutter (22382): #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
I/flutter (22382): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
I/flutter (22382): #11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #13     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
I/flutter (22382): #14     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
I/flutter (22382): #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
I/flutter (22382): #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
I/flutter (22382): #17     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
I/flutter (22382): #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
I/flutter (22382): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
I/flutter (22382): #20     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #21     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #22     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3907:5)
I/flutter (22382): #23     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4053:11)
I/flutter (22382): #24     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3902:5)
I/flutter (22382): #25     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
I/flutter (22382): #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
I/flutter (22382): #27     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
I/flutter (22382): #28     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
I/flutter (22382): #29     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
I/flutter (22382): #30     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
I/flutter (22382): #31     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
I/flutter (22382): #32     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
I/flutter (22382): #33     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
I/flutter (22382): #34     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
I/flutter (22382): #35     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5198:32)
I/flutter (22382): #36     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
I/flutter (22382): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
I/flutter (22382): #38     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5092:14)
I/flutter (22382): #39     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3084:14)
I/flutter (22382): #40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
I/flutter (22382): #41     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
I/flutter (22382): #42     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #43     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #44     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #45     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
I/flutter (22382): #46     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #47     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #48     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #49     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3981:5)
I/flutter (22382): #50     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #51     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3077:38)
I/flutter (22382): #52     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2887:12)
I/flutter (22382): #53     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #54     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #55     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
I/flutter (22382): #56     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #57     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #58     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #59     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
I/flutter (22382): #60     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #61     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #62     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #63     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
I/flutter (22382): #64     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #65     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #66     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #67     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
I/flutter (22382): #68     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #69     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4817:32)
I/flutter (22382): #70     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5208:17)
I/flutter (22382): #71     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #72     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #73     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #74     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
I/flutter (22382): #75     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #76     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #77     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #78     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
I/flutter (22382): #79     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #80     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #81     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #82     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
I/flutter (22382): #83     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #84     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
I/flutter (22382): #85     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #86     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #87     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #88     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3981:5)
I/flutter (22382): #89     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #90     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5099:14)
I/flutter (22382): #91     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #92     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #93     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #94     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
I/flutter (22382): #95     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #96     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #97     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #98     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4085:5)
I/flutter (22382): #99     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #100    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #101    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #102    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
I/flutter (22382): #103    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #104    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #105    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #106    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4219:5)
I/flutter (22382): #107    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2876:15)
I/flutter (22382): #108    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3935:16)
I/flutter (22382): #109    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3721:5)
I/flutter (22382): #110    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2340:33)
I/flutter (22382): #111    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:700:20)
I/flutter (22382): #112    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:285:5)
I/flutter (22382): #113    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1016:15)
I/flutter (22382): #114    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:958:9)
I/flutter (22382): #115    _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:874:5)
I/flutter (22382): #119    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:236:10)
I/flutter (22382): #120    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:194:3)
I/flutter (22382): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (22382): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Can you add the content of your console so we can see any additional info about the error you are encountering? Thanks!

Comment: @Genez.Ragan Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In initState, you are calling an *async* function _getCurrentUser. So, naturally this function will execute asynchronously while initState continues and the page is rendered with _uname as null.

Red screen is being displayed because of a null pointer exception being thrown when you are displaying the name.

Either initialize _uname with an empty string

```
  String _uname = '';
```

or use null aware operator while displaying name

```
child: Text("Welcome " + _uname ?? '',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))),
        ]));
```

Comment: I initialize _uname with an empty string and also I had to move _uname = item['fname'] inside the setstate(). Now I don't have red screen. Thank you!